# LWJGL and Slick having troubles catching keystroke

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm having trouble with LWJGL and slick. What i am attempting to do is to display a certain amount of text, and when a button is pressed (in this case it would be return), the screen clears and new text is displayed. I'm currently using this code

```
public void text() {
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Color.white.bind;
    font.drawString(0, 0, "text");
  while (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RETURN)) {
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    font.drawString(0, 0, "text (again)");
  }
}
//so on an so forth
```

But the problem with this is when i put in another one of these it creates a death loop.
is there a better way of doing this? I have tried If statements, but that has just made it appear then revert back to the first string.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that what is happening is that it executes repetitively, and that what you are trying to do is execute it once. The code for that would be:

```
while(Keyboard.next()) {
        if(Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
            switch(Keyboard.getEventKey()) {
            case Keyboard.KEY_RETURN:
                GL11.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                font.drawString(0, 0, "text (again)");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```